# Configure R to use utf-8 by default

Tags: r

To avoid problems when using R and RStudio, can R be configured to work with utf-8 by default? My system is windows 10 64 bit, R scripts are saved as ANSI, however when opening those same files with RStudio there are problems with the Latin characters, ñ, tildes, euro symbol €. I have to convert the files to change the character encoding, so that I can use them with RStudio.

From the R console:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio go to Tools bar, then click Global options (at the bottom):

See picture below: Click Code, then Saving -> you can set default text encoding

[image]

Comment: I have changed the settings in RStudio.

Comment: and in R RGui, is it possible?